# Cannot compile ssl_verify_fun in Windows 11

Tags: installation, erlang, elixir, phoenix-live-view

### Background

I have a phoenix application in Windows 11. Unfortunately for me, I cannot compile the application because of a dependency error in Windows.

### What I tried

First I tried the downloading Erlang from the official website (https://www.erlang.org/downloads), and Elixir
1.15.4 for OTP 26 (https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#windows)

Unfortunately for me, I was greeted with an error when running `mix phx.server`.

```
$ mix deps.compile ssl_verify_fun
==> ssl_verify_fun
Compiling 7 files (.erl)
src/ssl_verify_hostname.erl:16: can't find include lib "public_key/include/public_key.hrl"
```

So, this lead me into this Elixir thread where the same issue happens for Ubuntu:

https://elixirforum.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-compile-ssl-verify-fun-fails/32802

The solution found was for the user to install a special erlang package for Ubuntu, `erlang-dev`. However, since I am on Windows, I don't really have that option.

So I removed both Erlang and Elixir and installed them using scoop, hoping the older versions of both Elixir and Erlang available there would be free of this issue.

With scoop I am now using:

```
elixir 1.15.4   main   2023-07-27 10:27:04
erlang 25.3.2.4 main   2023-07-27 10:10:31
```

### Error

However, this still does not fix the issue, as I am greeted with a barrage of errors:

```
==> ssl_verify_fun
Compiling 7 files (.erl)
src/ssl_verify_fingerprint.erl:15:14: can't find include lib "public_key/include/public_key.hrl"
%   15| -include_lib("public_key/include/public_key.hrl").
%     |              ^

src/ssl_verify_pk.erl:14:14: can't find include lib "public_key/include/public_key.hrl"
%   14| -include_lib("public_key/include/public_key.hrl").
%     |              ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:13:14: can't find include lib "public_key/include/public_key.hrl"
%   13| -include_lib("public_key/include/public_key.hrl").
%     |              ^

src/ssl_verify_fingerprint.erl:27:26: record 'OTPCertificate' undefined
%   27| -spec verify_fun(Cert :: #'OTPCertificate'{},
%     |                          ^

src/ssl_verify_pk.erl:26:26: record 'OTPCertificate' undefined
%   26| -spec verify_fun(Cert :: #'OTPCertificate'{},
%     |                          ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:23:34: undefined macro 'id-ce-subjectAltName'
%   23|   AltSubject = select_extension(?'id-ce-subjectAltName', Extensions),
%     |                                  ^

src/ssl_verify_fingerprint.erl:29:39: record 'Extension' undefined
%   29|                           {extension, #'Extension'{}}, InitialUserState :: term()) ->
%     |                                       ^

src/ssl_verify_pk.erl:28:39: record 'Extension' undefined
%   28|                           {extension, #'Extension'{}}, InitialUserState :: term()) ->
%     |                                       ^

src/ssl_verify_hostname.erl:16:14: can't find include lib "public_key/include/public_key.hrl"
%   16| -include_lib("public_key/include/public_key.hrl").
%     |              ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:9:2: function extract_dns_names/1 undefined
%    9| -export([extract_dns_names/1,
%     |  ^

src/ssl_verify_fingerprint.erl:52:39: record 'OTPCertificate' undefined
%   52| -spec verify_cert_fingerprint(Cert :: #'OTPCertificate'{}, Fingerprint :: fingerprint()) ->
%     |                                       ^

src/ssl_verify_pk.erl:51:30: record 'OTPCertificate' undefined
%   51| -spec verify_cert_pk(Cert :: #'OTPCertificate'{}, Pk :: pk()) ->
%     |                              ^

src/ssl_verify_hostname.erl:28:26: record 'OTPCertificate' undefined
%   28| -spec verify_fun(Cert :: #'OTPCertificate'{},
%     |                          ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:19:2: spec for undefined function extract_dns_names/1
%   19| -spec extract_dns_names(Cert :: #'OTPCertificate'{}) -> [] | [string()].
%     |  ^

src/ssl_verify_hostname.erl:30:39: record 'Extension' undefined
%   30|                           {extension, #'Extension'{}}, InitialUserState :: term()) ->
%     |                                       ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:19:33: record 'OTPCertificate' undefined
%   19| -spec extract_dns_names(Cert :: #'OTPCertificate'{}) -> [] | [string()].
%     |                                 ^

src/ssl_verify_hostname.erl:46:36: record 'OTPCertificate' undefined
%   46| -spec verify_cert_hostname(Cert :: #'OTPCertificate'{}, Hostname :: hostname()) ->
%     |                                    ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:32:26: record 'OTPCertificate' undefined
%   32| -spec extract_cn(Cert :: #'OTPCertificate'{}) -> {error, no_common_name} | {ok, string()} | {error, invalid}.
%     |                          ^

src/ssl_verify_hostname.erl:76:38: record 'OTPCertificate' undefined
%   76|                              Cert :: #'OTPCertificate'{},
%     |                                      ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:34:17: record 'OTPCertificate' undefined
%   34|   TBSCert = Cert#'OTPCertificate'.tbsCertificate,
%     |                 ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:35:32: record 'OTPTBSCertificate' undefined
%   35|   {rdnSequence, List} = TBSCert#'OTPTBSCertificate'.subject,
%     |                                ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:38:26: record 'OTPCertificate' undefined
%   38| -spec extract_pk(Cert :: #'OTPCertificate'{}) -> {error, no_common_name} | #'SubjectPublicKeyInfo'{}.
%     |                          ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:38:76: record 'SubjectPublicKeyInfo' undefined
%   38| -spec extract_pk(Cert :: #'OTPCertificate'{}) -> {error, no_common_name} | #'SubjectPublicKeyInfo'{}.
%     |                                                                            ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:40:17: record 'OTPCertificate' undefined
%   40|   TBSCert = Cert#'OTPCertificate'.tbsCertificate,
%     |                 ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:41:26: record 'OTPTBSCertificate' undefined
%   41|   PublicKeyInfo = TBSCert#'OTPTBSCertificate'.subjectPublicKeyInfo,
%     |                          ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:42:16: record 'OTPSubjectPublicKeyInfo' undefined
%   42|   PublicKeyInfo#'OTPSubjectPublicKeyInfo'.subjectPublicKey.
%     |                ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:48:24: record 'Extension' undefined
%   48| -spec extensions_list([#'Extension'{}] | asn1_NOVALUE) -> [] | [#'Extension'{}].
ean it with "mix deps.clean ssl_verify_fun"n, "mix compile" failed. Errors may have been logged above. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile ssl_verify_fun --force", update it with "mix deps.update ssl_verify_fun" or cl%     |                        ^
src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:48:65: record 'Extension' undefined
%   48| -spec extensions_list([#'Extension'{}] | asn1_NOVALUE) -> [] | [#'Extension'{}].
%     |                                                                 ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:55:39: record 'Extension' undefined
%   55| -spec select_extension(Id :: term(), [#'Extension'{}]) -> undefined | #'Extension'{}.
%     |                                       ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:55:71: record 'Extension' undefined
%   55| -spec select_extension(Id :: term(), [#'Extension'{}]) -> undefined | #'Extension'{}.
%     |                                                                       ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:57:28: record 'Extension' undefined
%   57|   Matching = [Extension || #'Extension'{extnID = ExtId} = Extension <- Extensions, ExtId =:= Id],
%     |                            ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:57:84: variable 'ExtId' is unbound
%   57|   Matching = [Extension || #'Extension'{extnID = ExtId} = Extension <- Extensions, ExtId =:= Id],
%     |                                                                                    ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:75:15: record 'AttributeTypeAndValue' undefined
%   75| extract_cn2([[#'AttributeTypeAndValue'{type={2, 5, 4, 3},
%     |               ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:77:39: variable 'CN' is unbound
%   77|   ssl_verify_fun_encodings:get_string(CN);
%     |                                       ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:49:1: Warning: function extensions_list/1 is unused
%   49| extensions_list(E) ->
%     | ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:56:1: Warning: function select_extension/2 is unused
%   56| select_extension(Id, Extensions) ->
%     | ^

src/ssl_verify_fun_cert_helpers.erl:64:1: Warning: function extract_dns_names_from_alt_names/2 is unused
%   64| extract_dns_names_from_alt_names([ExtValue | Rest], Acc) ->
%     | ^
```

At this point, given my setup is on Windows, I don't know what else to try.

### Question

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What version of `ssl_verify_fun` are you on? You might need to bump it to include the fix mentioned in https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/12653

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

After some more digging I found out this issue:

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/12653

Which represents my problem. Basically Elixir does not check the correct paths for the missing file:

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/12681

Now, there is a possible workaround for this issue. By forcing your application to use a more updated version of the dependency in question (`ssl_verify_fun`), you can add this to your `mix.exs` file:

> {:ssl_verify_fun, "~> 1.1.7", manager: :rebar3, override: true}

However, I don’t really like this. If tomorrow the same thing happens, you have to overwrite again. And when overwrites start conflicting with each other, then you really have a problem.

In my case, I found which application was using the old version of `ssl_verify_fun` by looking at `mix.lock`. It was `hackney`.

However, instead of going through every dependency and trying to fix it, I took the more nuclear approach. I deleted my `mix.lock` and then run `mix deps.update --all`.

This forced some older dependencies to update. After that a simple `mix deps.get` fixed the issue and `mix phx.server` worked.

You can find more information in the Elixir Forum thread:

https://elixirforum.com/t/cannot-compile-ssl-verify-fun-in-windows-11/57265/4

Answer (score 0):

I wish people who are trying to compile C code would learn a bit more about the mechanics of compiling C code. Because off the top of my head I'd say that your LIB path doesn't include that `public_key/include` directory.  But how you set the LIB path is a bit tricky all by itself because it sort of depends on which compiler/linker you're using.

Also, in your case, I cannot tell if you're trying under WSL or not.  However, that said, take a look at this link: [How To Build Erlang/OTP on Windows](https://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/install-win32). I know you were asking about ssl_verify_fun but the idea is the same; you need to get the C code compiling and linking correctly and the stuff at the link covers that. Mainly what you want to make sure is that you've got your INCLUDE and LIB paths set correctly.

Frankly it's a fairly complex trick (given WSL and the need for the MS C++ compiler and all) so it's really pretty tough to give a specific answer to your question.  Maybe try following the linked guide and see if you can't narrow down the issue.